# LookupHost in Google App Engine errors

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, go

I've tried the following code:

```
addresses, error := net.LookupHost("google.com")
```

in regular Go and in the Google App Engine SDK, and it generally works fine.

However in a production GAE instance, it produces the following error:

```
error reading DNS config: open /etc/resolv.conf: operation not permitted
```

Will this be fixed, is there a workaround, can I change anything in the `app.yaml` configuration etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use the AppEngine API:

- http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/appengine-go/appengine/socket#LookupIP

Note you'll need a context there as well.

Comment: Works for me, thanks! I wonder why appengine/socket isn't documented here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/apis